# Determinar si un string contiene a otro string Python

Tags: string, substring

Estoy intentando encontrar un algoritmo que detecte si un string contiene a otro string, aunque sea repartido en él. Me explico mejor. Tengo dos string:

```
a = 'Amazon'
b = 'idswenjecttama.top/zon.erjk'
```

En este caso, el primer string (a) en encuentra repartido entre las posiciones 11,12,13,19,20 y 21 del segundo string (b).
Me es suficiente con saber que el string a se encuentre dentro del b. En caso contrario, me serviría una puntuación que me ayudase a saber en qué medida contiene al otro string.
He estado buscando algunos algoritmos, como Jaccard, similitud coseno, etc. Pero todos ellos son aplicados a textos (los textos se dividen en palabras) y en mi caso no puedo dividir el string en caracteres. He encontrado otros como el algoritmo de Levenshtein, pero al ser siempre de distinta longitud no me sirve.
Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si comprendí bien la pregunta, buscas algo como esto.

```
a= "amazon"
b = "idswenjecttama.top/zon.erjk"
incluidas=0
for elem in a:
   if elem in b:
     incluida++
porcentajeDeInclusion=incluidas*(100%)/len(a)
```

Comment: Cómo no se me había ocurrido... muchísimas gracias! Estaba tan empeñado en buscar un algoritmo que no pensé en la facilidad del problema.